# Oracle Variable Not Bound - ORA-01008

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I've been looking around and can't seem to figure this one out, I've looked at a few similar issues on stack but still stuck. I'm getting a `ORA-01008: not all vaiables bound` message when I try to run the below block.

```
DECLARE
     io_TarId0   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId1   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId2   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId3   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     oi_Result   PLS_INTEGER := 0;
     on_ErrID    system_errors.sys_err_id%TYPE := '-99999999999999';
BEGIN
     PKG.rates(:io_TarId0, '3791', '24', '6', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, :oi_Result, :on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(:io_TarId1, '3791', '24', '4', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, :oi_Result, :on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(:io_TarId2, '3791', '24', '5', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, :oi_Result, :on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(:io_TarId3, '3791', '24', '3', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 1, :oi_Result, :on_ErrID);
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear - your query uses bind variables, but you didn't declare them.

Since apparently you want to use local variables, just get rid of the ':' :

```
DECLARE
     io_TarId0   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId1   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId2   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     io_TarId3   rates.r_id%TYPE := 0;
     oi_Result   PLS_INTEGER := 0;
     on_ErrID    system_errors.sys_err_id%TYPE := '-99999999999999';
BEGIN
     PKG.rates(io_TarId0, '3791', '24', '6', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, oi_Result, on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(io_TarId1, '3791', '24', '4', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, oi_Result, on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(io_TarId2, '3791', '24', '5', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 0, oi_Result, on_ErrID);
     PKG.rates(io_TarId3, '3791', '24', '3', '', '123', '', TO_DATE('18/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), '', 1, oi_Result, on_ErrID);
END;
```